# Cron Job to trigger AWS Lambda not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, serverless, cron-task

I want to trigger my AWS lambda function on 15th of every month but my function is triggering after every 30 minutes. My function in Serverless.yml is

```
monthlyTbAlert:
    warmup: true
    handler: handlers/monthly-tbalert/index.monthlyTbAlert
    timeout: 60
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 0 10 15 1/1 ? *)
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to debug your cron expressions before deploying them, you can go to CloudWatch -> Rules and test them there. It's a very useful playground if you're unsure about what may be going on.

If we grab the expression provided in @Stargazer's answer (which, by the way, is very accurate) and paste it in CloudWatch Rules, we can see when the next triggers will happen:

[image]

By using yours, however, we can see no events are shown. If you say it is running every 30 minutes, then there potentially is a bug in CloudWatch rules that triggers invalid expressions every 30 minutes:

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect place to test cron for AWS and should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html), the format is cron(Minutes Hours Day-of-month Month Day-of-week Year)

So you should use this:

`0` - Minute 0 of the hours
`10`- Hours of the day. So, 10:00
`15`- 15th day of the month
`*` - Execute it every month
`?` - Regardless of the day of the week
`*`- Every year

So, your cron expression should be `0 10 15 * ? *` To execute your cron every 15th day of the month at 10:00AM